# Ruby on Rails Link_to is not clickable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, link-to

Today i encountered with an error, where a `link_to` tag is not clickable in my rails app. When I use some other `link_to` tag like ("`<%=link_to ""%>` with an empty or some other tag o in bottom of the page all other link to tag is working.

If I remove that bottom `link_to` tag, other tags are not clickable. I have searched a lot for more than 6-7 hrs, but have found no fix. What might be the cause?

First, it works fine, after I stop the server and start it again, it's not clickable.

Comment: You are probably generating invalid HTML in your view. You might be missing some closing tag, or you are not closing quotes of tag attributes correctly. In any case, there is probably a typo somewhere in your view.

Comment: ^^ This. It's extremely hard to give a concrete answer to this without a [mcve] of the problem, but crucially I'd check the actual HTML being generated on your page. Also... Perhaps this is actually being caused by some CSS/JS setup, and the starting/stopping of the server is affecting webpacker?

Comment: ^^ This excepting I would replace *"extremely hard"* with *"impossible"*. Any proposal would be pure conjecture and any positive result pure happenstance